# Javascript function validation not working for changing button value

Tags: javascript, function

This function isn't working. Can anyone please help? When I press the validate button, nothing happens.

```
<script>
function validate()
{
    int user =  document.getElementById("uname");
    if(user=="rohit")
        document.getElementById("btnsubmit").value = "Sucess";
    else
        document.getElementById("btnsubmit").value = "Fail";
}
</script>

<body>
<div>
    <table id="tbl-aut">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h2>Enter Login Details</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >Username<span style="color:red">*</span></td>

            <td><input type="text" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="btnsubmit" type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validate()"><td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: where is the element with an id tag of 'uname' ? There are many mistakes in your code here is an example on w3 schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp you use the try it yourself on there

Comment: In `JavaScript` there is no `int` type. you can use `var`, `let` or `const` to define your variables.

Comment: When will an element equal a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is happening because you have a few problems:

First, you have a syntax error. `int` is not a valid keyword in JavaScript. In JavaScript, data types are implicitly determined. You cannot explicitly specify a type (and there is no integer type in JavaScript anyway).

Next, you are attempting to check an object (the text field) against the value stored in the object. You need to access the `value` property of the text field to get the data entered into it.

Also, you are attempting to get an object with an `id` of `uname`, but you didn't set up that `id` in the text field at all.

Lastly, and this is more of a best-practice thing. Always wrap the true/false branches of your `if` statements with curly braces `{}`. Although it is syntactically OK to omit them when there is only one statement in the branch, this is a well-know bug magnet.

```html
<script>
function validate() {
    var user =  document.getElementById("uname");
    if(user.value =="rohit"){
        document.getElementById("btnsubmit").value = "Sucess";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("btnsubmit").value = "Fail";
    }
}
</script>

<body>
<div>
    <table id="tbl-aut">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h2>Enter Login Details</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >Username<span style="color:red">*</span></td>

            <td><input id="uname" type="text" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="btnsubmit" type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validate()"><td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
```